# Audio Voice to Text Amazon Lex

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-lex, aws-sdk

I want to convert audio file to text using Amazon Lex.Is there any javascript sdk provided by Amazon to do so?.I am writing to a nodejs application to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Amazon API "Lex Runtime Service" with the **[Javascript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexRuntime.html)**.
With that, you can send audio files using the `PostContent` Method.

Here are the audio formats that are allowed:

### [PostContent Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostContent.html)

> **contentType**
>   You pass this value as the Content-Type HTTP header.
>
> Indicates the audio format or text. The header value must start with one of the following prefixes:
>
> **PCM format**, audio data must be in little-endian byte order.
>
> audio/l16; rate=16000; channels=1
>
> audio/x-l16; sample-rate=16000; channel-count=1
>
> audio/lpcm; sample-rate=8000; sample-size-bits=16; channel-count=1; is-big-endian=false
>
> **Opus format**
>
> audio/x-cbr-opus-with-preamble; preamble-size=0; bit-rate=256000; frame-size-milliseconds=4
>
> **Text format**
>
> text/plain; charset=utf-8